# Jest Async/Await fails callback regardless? typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test some typescript, tests all worked until recently and not certain what changed.

Below is a mock that fails consistently saying

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout
specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

Tried so many things I'm out of ideas of what I'm doing wrong...

leaving in comments to point to some of the previous attempts...

which includes:

- set timeout to 100+ seconds
- calling `done()` without any kind of delay
- mocking promises to delay response and calling `done()`
- eliminating the use of `done`
- uses `Promise` vs `async`

always the same error about callback not being invoked

```
console.warn = jest.fn();
console.error = jest.fn();

describe('Test async await', () => {
    beforeAll(async (done) => {
        jest.setTimeout(5000);
        done();
    });


    // test('Check async callback.', async (done) => {
    test('Check async callback.', async () => {
        const waitFor = 2;
        console.log(`skipping wait -- what happens?`);
        // console.log(`starting to wait ${waitFor} seconds`);
        // setTimeout(() => {
        //     console.log(`finished waiting ${waitFor} seconds`);
        //     done();
        // }, waitFor * 1000);

        const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

        await timeout(waitFor * 1000);
        // done();

        console.log(`finished waiting ${waitFor} seconds`);
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Running

```
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
```

I'm assuming it's simple but not obvious?

Comment: Works on my machine ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Only difference is I had to add a type to the `ms` variable for the compiler to be happy.